# I did an agar gel electrophoresis but I could not see DNA, why?

Tags: lab-techniques, pcr

After performing a PCR, I ran the products (700 bp) in an agar gel electrophoresis along with a Genedirex ladder (100 bp), but the transilluminator did not reveal them.

Comment: Please give us information as to how your prep was done, because otherwise our guess is as good as yours.

Comment: Dinesh, could you take a photo of the gel? It would be helpful.

Comment: Assuming you loaded everything correctly, if you CANNOT see the ladder, you forgot to add EtBr. If you can see ladder but no product, then there is no product, or at least not enough. You can try to concentrate or amplify your DNA sample to increase the signal, if you have anything.

Answer (score 1):

One common reason you can't see your DNA is because you didn't put any EtBr / GelRed into your gel. Do you have enough PCR product to run it on another agarose gel?

Comment: When i ran the same ladder(100 bp) again on the same gel i got ladder on the gel.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check if you added following two before loading on a gel

1. EtBr
2. Loading dye

Since you can't see the ladder either, amount of PCR products may not be the reason.

Comment: The same thing happened with me again this time i could see the loading dye but not the pcr product and ladder.